# Adding int numbers?

Tags: c#, int

```
public static int addIntNumbers()
{
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int sum = 0;
    while (input !=0)
    {        
        sum += input % 10;
        input /= 10;
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I don't understand this syntax: After the `while` condition, `sum += input % 10`, which basically means `sum = sum(which is 0) + input % 10`, so lets say I input 24 so the sum of this should be 4, I think ?

And then the second line which I have no idea what it is even doing.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: [C# Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Comment: The downvotes are likely for lack of reasearch effort, since all the operators used are documented online. You could also set a breakpoint and step through the code to see how the values are changing.

Answer (score 0):

The best way might be to add comments. However I can already tell that whoever wrote this, did not know what he as doing. For starters, there were not comments, the naming is abysmal and the I/O is actually handeled inside the function.

```
//The name is not right. This is not a proper sum function
//I think it is getting a sum of all digits in the input
public static int addIntNumbers()
{
    //Get a input from the user, parse it to int
    //That really belons outside. Just the int in per argument
    int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    //Initialize sum to 0
    int sum = 0;

    //Input is also used as sort of "running variable".
    //The loop will break if input reaches 0
    while (input !=0)
    {
        //sum = sum + input % 10
        //It tries to divide input by 10, get's the rest, then adds that rest to sum
        sum += input % 10;
        //Divide input by 10. Note that all decimal parts will be dropped
        //That means it will reach 0 invariably
        input /= 10;
        //Output the current sum for debugging
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
    //The function returns
    return sum;

}
```

Comment: it was me who wrote this, unfortunately not the best programmer there is, sorry.Regarding the code I now see, cause the decimal part is what was bugging me, but another thing that I sort of do not get is this. Lets say the user inputs 24, so the first line of code, after the while condition, will calculate 4, the second line of code will calculate 2, so 2 + 4 is 6, which is the correct answer, however which line actually sums up the 2 and 4 ?

Comment: @MatasMikelionis The first loop will add the 4 to sum and then the second loop will add 2.  So on the second loop `sum += imput%10;` is doing the 4+2.

Comment: @MatasMikelionis And that is why commenting is so imporant. In 6 months you no longer have any idea what you were thinking :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code calculates digit-by-digit sum of an integer (the sum is positive if input is positive, negative if input is negative).
If you are a C# beginner, this might help you:

```
    while (input !=0)
    {

        sum = sum + (input % 10); //sum = sum + remainder of division by ten (separation of least significant digit)
        input = input / 10; //input is integer-divided by ten, which results in discarding of the least significant digit
        Console.WriteLine(sum);
    }
```

If you don't understand, get familiar with a difference between
    `4/6`
and `4.0/6`.
The first one is integer division, the other is floating point division.

Comment: aaaa, I see, cause the decimal part is what was bugging me, but another thing that I sort of do not get is this. Lets say the user inputs 24, so the first line of code, after the while condition, will calculate 4, the second line of code will calculate 2, so 2 + 4 is 6, which is the correct answer, however which line actually sums up the 2 and 4 ?

Comment: Input 24 is processed as:
1) Calculate the input mod 10, which is 4, and add it to sum (so sum is 4 now)
2) Integer-divide the input (which is now 24) by 10 and store it back, so input is 24/10 = 2 now (4 are discarded, because it's an integer division)
3) Because input is 2 now, while cycle goes to next iteration:
4) 2 mod 10 is 2, which is added to sum, so sum is 6
5) input 2 / 10 is 0, which is stored to input
6) while cycle does not continue (since input = 0) and sum is 6. The 2+4=6 calculation is done in the second iteration of the while cycle.

Comment: ooooh, I see now, your help is really appreciated, have a great day lol !

Comment: oh and one last question if you so happen to see, when does the while loop break ? when it actually calculates the sum of int numbers ?

Comment: The loops breaks when `input /= 10;` is executed with an input less than 10. If input < 10, then result of this line is zero (so the following check of input value at the top of while returns false, thus no next iteration is done).

Answer (score 0):

Some things to help you understand what's going on here:

First, assuming you're in Visual Studio, you can set a break point in your code by clicking to the left of the line number, in the margin. A red dot will show up and when your code hits that point, it will pause. While paused, you can look at the "Locals" tab or hover over variable names in your code to see what values are at that point in time. You can then use F10 to step forward one line at a time and see how things change.

Second, the /= operator is similar to the += operator, except with division. So, "x /= 10" is exactly the same as "x = x / 10".

This program is adding up each digit of the number you type in by getting the ones digit, adding it to sum, then dividing the number by 10 to get rid of the old ones digit.